# De que maneira eu poderia criar uma classe que servisse tanto para API sandbox quanto API produção?

Tags: c#

Estou integrando a API da CIELO no meu sistema, eles tem dois tipos de API, a sandbox e produção.
Cada qual com a sua `merchantKey` , `merchantID` , `apiUrl` e `apiUrlQuery` de consulta, ou seja tenho 4 constantes para cada ambiente. Minha ideia inicial foi implementar o seguinte:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SiteTeste.APIS.CIELO
{
    public class CieloAPI
    {
        string merchantKey, merchantID, apiUrl, apiUrlQuery;
        public CieloAPI(string merchantKey, string merchantID, string apiUrl, string apiUrlQuery)
        {
            this.merchantKey = merchantKey;
            this.merchantID = merchantID;
            this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
            this.apiUrlQuery = apiUrl;
        }
     }
}
```

Porém sempre que eu fosse instanciar uma nova classe `CieloAPI` teria que ficar passando as chaves, fora que eu não saberia qual seria a chave de sandbox e produção.

Não quero tudo mastigado, porém preciso de um norte de qual recurso utilizar, classe abstrata? interface? e etc..

Comment: Captura a informação de algum arquivo que vá ser diferente em desenvolvimento e em produção. Provavelmente o `[web|app].config` é a melhor escolha.

Comment: Você poder usar uma [diretiva de pré-processamento](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc564864.aspx).

Comment: Utilize variáveis de ambiente ou arquivos de configuração... você pode atribuir essas configurações na startup através de uma classe estática ou fazer a injeção de dependência